# VarienForm not working in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, magento-1.9

Hello I am developing a login and register form in magento. For form validation I am using this code

```
var registerForm = new VarienForm('register-form', true);

var loginForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);

if (this.validator && this.validator.validate()) {
    this.form.submit();
}
```

when i am using this code in phtml with script tag it is working but when I am putting it in js and calling through xml it is not working here is my xml code

```
<custom_abc_index>

    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

   <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/custom_abc/customLoginRegister.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="custom_abc/custom" name="custom" template="custom_abc/Custom.phtml"></block>
    </reference>


</custom_abc_index>
```

To check whether js is loading or not i put alert() in it , I got the popup but I don't know why the validation code is not working. Any Help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple validation than better you use magento in built validation class form validation

refer this

[Form Validation classes](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/custom-form-validation-magento)